# Can I navigate to a tab within a standard Lightning Tabs component from a custom component on the page?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-app-builder

Consider the following screenshot:
[image: Console Screen Shot]

This is a standard 3 column Lightning Page Layout; the center section contains a standard Tabs component.  The highlighted tab "Related Cases" contains a custom lightning component.  The "Related Open Cases" section in the right-hand section (also highlighted) is another custom component.  Is there any way to present a link (or button, whatever) in that component that will cause the Tabs component (in Lightning App Builder) in the center section to navigate to the "Related Cases" component?

While the screenshot is showing Service Cloud Console, I only need the navigation to occur within a single Lightning Page Layout (Record Home), allowing a component on the page to navigate the standard Tabs component on the same page.  Is it possible?